# How to fail test case deliberately in allure report using playwright in the try catch block

Tags: playwright, allure

Need to pass status as failed in allure report in try catch block.
I am using allure-playwright reporter with java script
For example

```
 try {
      let result = await expect.soft(Expected).toEqual(Actual);
 if (!result && Expected != Actual) {
        throw new Error();
      }} 
catch (error) 
{
allure report: status: failed.
}
```

Comment: Did you check https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo#test-info-fail-1 
this can mark the test as failed in playwright html-report with description. In allure will be only failed.

Comment: I tried, just showing annotation - fail in the report, but the test is passed